# Where can I find a list of compatible audio cards?

Tags: hardware, compatibility, soundcard

I have a creative SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio, And i faced so many problems with this card regarding compatibility with Linux.

Now i am looking for a new audio card and want to make sure that this time it will be compatible with linux.

If you don't know a websites that has a list of supported Linux audio cards just tell me what audio card you are using on Linux.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the [hardware compatibility list on linuxcompatible.org](http://www.linuxcompatible.org/compatdb/lists/hardware_linux.html) can help you.

Maybe this can help too: [Sound Cards & Drivers - linux-sound.org](http://www.linux-sound.org/drivers.html)

Here is another list: [Sound cards - Linux Hardware Compatibility HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Hardware-HOWTO/sound.html)

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu specifically, see [HardwareSupport/Components/SoundCards](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsSoundCards) on the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of [certified audio cards](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/AUDIO) in the component certification catalog.

- [Component Catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog)

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look here at the [ALSA project wiki](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Main)'s list of supported sound cards. ([Here's the site search](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Special:Search?ns100=1&searchx=Search)).